# Compare two dataframes and keep the rows that overlap

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes: one with a single column(A) and another with two columns(B). I want to compare data frame A with a column of dataframe B (A contains the same type of data as the column in B and some of the rows overlap). Then I want to keep the rows of dataframe B that are overlapping.

Example:

```
A = pd.DataFrame([['Smile1'], ['Smile4'], ['Smile6']], columns=['Smiles'])

B = pd.DataFrame([[24, 'Smile1'], [33, 'Smile2'], [2, 'Smile3'], 
[85, 'Smile4'], [68, 'Smile5'], [102, 'Smile6']], columns=['ID', 'Smiles'])
```

In this example I would like to keep Smile1, 4 and 6 and their IDs, preferably create a new dataframe that contains those columns, like this:

`C = pd.DataFrame([[24, 'Smile1'], [85, 'Smile4'], [102, 'Smile6']], columns=['ID', 'Smiles'])`

My actual data frames are much bigger.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
B[B["Smiles"].isin(A["Smiles"])]
```

Output:

```
Out[8]: 
    ID  Smiles
0   24  Smile1
3   85  Smile4
5  102  Smile6
```

Answer (score 1):

Check with

```
C = B[B['Smiles'].isin(A['Smiles'])]
C
Out[73]: 
    ID  Smiles
0   24  Smile1
3   85  Smile4
5  102  Smile6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pd.DataFrame.merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

```py
C = pd.merge(B, A, on=['Smiles'])
C
    ID  Smiles
0   24  Smile1
1   85  Smile4
2  102  Smile6
```

Or With `isin` and `reset_index` would be

```py
C = B[B.Smiles.isin(A.Smiles)].reset_index(drop=True)
```